# spring-integration unit test outbound-channel adapter

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-integration

i have the following configuration

```
<int:channel id="notificationChannel" datatype="com.mycompany.integration.NotificationMessage">
        <int:queue message-store="jdbc-message-store" capacity="1000" />
    </int:channel>

    <int:outbound-channel-adapter ref="notificationHandler"
        method="handle" channel="notificationChannel" >
        <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="100" fixed-delay="60000"
            time-unit="MILLISECONDS" >
            <int:transactional isolation="DEFAULT" />
        </int:poller>
    </int:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

now i want to unit-test this, i need to wait for the message being processed correctly in the test, i tried it with an interceptor but that doesn't work because i could only sync on message delivery but not on successful processing of the message. implement sending a reply when the procesing is done but this would mean that would implement this only to make my unit-test work, in production there wouldn't be a replyChannel set in the message-header. how can i realize syncing on successful processing of the request without implementing it in the messageHandler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Spring Integration 2.2.x, you can do this with an advice...

```
public class CompletionAdvice extends AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice {

    private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    @Override
    protected Object doInvoke(ExecutionCallback callback, Object target, Message<?> message) throws Exception {
        Object result = callback.execute();
        latch.countDown();
        return result;
    }

    public CountDownLatch getLatch() {
        return latch;
    }

}
```

In your test environment, add the advice to the adapter's handler with a bean factory post processor.

```
public class AddCompletionAdvice implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    private final Collection<String> handlers;

    private final Collection<String> replyProducingHandlers;

    public AddCompletionAdvice(Collection<String> handlers, Collection<String> replyProducingHandlers) {
        this.handlers = handlers;
        this.replyProducingHandlers = replyProducingHandlers;
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        for (String beanName : handlers) {
            defineAdviceAndInject(beanFactory, beanName, beanName + "CompletionAdvice");
        }
        for (String beanName : replyProducingHandlers) {
            String handlerBeanName = beanFactory.getAliases(beanName + ".handler")[0];
            defineAdviceAndInject(beanFactory, handlerBeanName, beanName + "CompletionAdvice");
        }
    }

    private void defineAdviceAndInject(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory, String beanName, String adviceBeanName) {
        BeanDefinition serviceHandler = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(beanName);
        BeanDefinition advice = new RootBeanDefinition(CompletionAdvice.class);
        ((BeanDefinitionRegistry) beanFactory).registerBeanDefinition(adviceBeanName, advice);
        serviceHandler.getPropertyValues().add("adviceChain", new RuntimeBeanReference(adviceBeanName));
    }

}
```

Add the post processor to the config `<bean class="foo.AddCompletionAdvice" />`.

Finally, inject the advice(s) into your test case

```
@ContextConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class TestAdvice {

    @Autowired
    private CompletionAdvice fooCompletionAdvice;

    @Autowired
    private CompletionAdvice barCompletionAdvice;

    @Autowired
    private MessageChannel input;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        Message<?> message = new GenericMessage<String>("Hello, world!");
        input.send(message);
        assertTrue(fooCompletionAdvice.getLatch().await(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        assertTrue(barCompletionAdvice.getLatch().await(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    }

}
```

and wait for the latch(es).

```
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="input"/>

<int:outbound-channel-adapter id="foo" channel="input" ref="x" method="handle"/>

<int:service-activator id="bar" input-channel="input" ref="x"/>

<bean class="foo.AddCompletionAdvice">
    <constructor-arg name="handlers">
        <list>
            <value>foo</value>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg name="replyProducingHandlers">
        <list>
            <value>bar</value>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="x" class="foo.Foo" />
```

I added these classes to a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/garyrussell/5481779)

EDIT: Updated to provide a general case for ultimate consumers (no reply) and reply producing consumers.

Comment: this looks great. i will mark this as the solution as soon as i've tried it out thanks.

Comment: i have set an id for the adapter and used your code. now i get

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'adviceChain' of bean class [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageHandler]: Bean property 'adviceChain' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Comment: i tried setting the advice chain on the poller instead of the channel-adapter which has this property, but the completionAdvice is not invoked

Comment: Sorry, I tested it with a `<service-activator/>` that returns null. I edited the post to show how to advise an outbound adapter.

Comment: thank you, the advice is called now, but it's a different object than the one autowired into my test-case so it waits on a different latch. i also explicity set the scope of bean advice-bean to singleton. i will try to introduce a layer of indirection to cope with this. can you post your spring-config as well please. maybe i'm doing something wrong there

Comment: ok, so i extracted the latch into a LatchHolder-Singleton bean and now everything works perfectly. thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry - my mistake - I didn't actually have time to test it; we need to inject a `RuntimeBeanReference` with the name of the advice instead of the `BeanDefinition`. I updated the answer. Of course, you could also have defined the advice in the context and injected it into both the post processor and test case (rather than creating the new bean definition.

Comment: Updated again with a general solution for both types of consumer.

Comment: @GaryRussell: Is it possible to use this in combination with the Java DSL? I just get the bean definition of the StandardIntegrationFlow, not the handler defined within.

Comment: Yes, but the details depend on how you define the flow - it's better to ask a new question showing your code and reference this question.

Comment: @GaryRussell Done this :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46409149/add-advicechain-to-standardintegrationflow-to-set-a-countdownlatch-on-a-message