# Adding advice to a mail inbound channel adapter

Tags: spring-integration

I am integration testing a spring integration flow, which starts with a Mail inbound channel adapter. I send test emails to a mock GreenMail email server and then test the expected outcome. But because the email is asynchronous, the test currently only passes if I wait after sending the mail, until the flow completes.

Here is the mail adapter config:

```
<int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="imapAdapter"
      store-uri="#{mailConnectionString}"
      java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties" channel="inboundChannel"
      should-delete-messages="false" should-mark-messages-as-read="true"
      auto-startup="true">
    <int:poller id="emailPoller" max-messages-per-poll="1" fixed-rate="5000">
    </int:poller>
</int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

So, with reference to this: [Adding Completion Advice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16277487/1892382), I thought I could simply wait for the completion advice and then continue testing. But you can't add advice to the mail adapter:

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'adviceChain' of bean class [org.springframework.integration.config.SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean]: Bean property 'adviceChain' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?`

Also tried the reply producing handler (from above link), but no bean was found.

So. How do I add advice to the inbound mail adapter? Or is there a better way to test the mail adapter once the entire flow completes?

**Update after answer suggestion**
I changed the test to add the advice within the set up.

```
@Autowired
private SourcePollingChannelAdapter emailAdapter;

private MyAdvice imapAdapterCompletionAdvice;

@Before
public void setup() throws Exception
{
    imapAdapterCompletionAdvice = new MyAdvice();
    List<Advice> theAdvice = new ArrayList<Advice>();
    theAdvice.add(imapAdapterCompletionAdvice);
    emailAdapter.setAdviceChain(theAdvice);
    emailAdapter.start();           
}
```

But the advice is not called. Am I missing something?

Here is the Advice class:

```
public class MyAdvice implements MethodInterceptor {

    private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        Object proceed = invocation.proceed();
        System.out.println(proceed);
        if (proceed instanceof Boolean) {
            Boolean mailReceived = (Boolean) proceed;
            if(mailReceived){
                latch.countDown();
            }
        }

        return proceed;
    }

    public CountDownLatch getLatch() {
        return latch;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely clear about what you are trying to do but inbound channel adapters are not message handlers (hence there is no handler bean). Polled inbound adapters are `MessageSource` but advising the source won't help because we invoke `receive()` and then send the message to the flow.

You can, however, add `Advice` objects to the `<poller/>`'s `advice-chain`.

An around advice would cover both the `receive()` (from the source) and `send()` to the channel so you can suspend the thread there.

You can just configure the advice on the poller directly.
If you want to do it programmatically, the `adviceChain` property is on the `pollerMetadata` field of the factory bean.

**EDIT**

I wouldn't use a `BFPP` for this any more - that question/answer is old; we now expose the handler as a bean name `id.handler` (and the messsage source similarly) so a `BFPP` is no longer needed.

It's much easier to wait for the bean to have been created rather than trying to inject the property into the bean definition.

I would do something like this...

1. Set auto-startup to false in the test case (use a property placeholder so it's true for production, false for test).
2. Inject the advice chain.
3. Start the adapter...

.

```
@Autowired
private SourcePollingChannelAdapter adapter;

...

@Test
public ... {

    this.adapter.setAdviceChain(...);
    this.adapter.start();
    ...
}
```

If you don't want to use this technique, use a `BeanPostProcessor` (`postProcessAfterInitialization` - after the factory bean has served up the channel adapter) rather than a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` to modify the advice chain.

You are correct in that the advice will be invoked even when there is no result from the poll.

You can use another advice (subclass of `AbstractMessageSourceAdvice` - [see Smart Polling](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#__smart_polling).

This advice advises just the `receive()` method and can tell if the result of the poll is a message; it can then arm your other advice to fire after the message is processed.

**EDIT2**

Need to reset the `initialized` flag so that the advice(s) will be re-applied. This can be done using reflection (Spring has a convenient `DirectFieldAccessor`).

If you're not comfortable with using reflection, you can `start/stop/start` which will do the same thing, but we need to make sure the first `start` doesn't actually trigger a poll.

Example with reflection:

```
@Autowired
private SourcePollingChannelAdapter adapter;

@Test
public void testAdvice() throws Exception {
    List<Advice> adviceChain = new ArrayList<Advice>();
    final AtomicBoolean hasMessage = new AtomicBoolean();
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    class MessageDetector extends AbstractMessageSourceAdvice {

        @Override
        public boolean beforeReceive(MessageSource<?> source) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public Message<?> afterReceive(Message<?> result, MessageSource<?> source) {
            hasMessage.set(result != null);
            System.out.println("has message:" + hasMessage.get());
            return result;
        }

    }
    adviceChain.add(new MessageDetector());
    class MyAdvice implements MethodInterceptor {

        @Override
        public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("in myAdvice before, hasmessage:" + hasMessage.get());
            Object proceed = invocation.proceed();
            System.out.println("in myAdvice after, hasmessage:" + hasMessage.get());
            latch.countDown();
            return proceed;
        }

    }
    adviceChain.add(new MyAdvice());
    adapter.setAdviceChain(adviceChain);
    new DirectFieldAccessor(adapter).setPropertyValue("initialized", false);
    adapter.start();
    assertTrue(latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
}
```

Example with trigger manipulation...

```
@Autowired
private SourcePollingChannelAdapter adapter;

@Test
public void testAdvice() throws Exception {
    List<Advice> adviceChain = new ArrayList<Advice>();
    final AtomicBoolean hasMessage = new AtomicBoolean();
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    class MessageDetector extends AbstractMessageSourceAdvice {

        @Override
        public boolean beforeReceive(MessageSource<?> source) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public Message<?> afterReceive(Message<?> result, MessageSource<?> source) {
            hasMessage.set(result != null);
            System.out.println("has message:" + hasMessage.get());
            return result;
        }

    }
    adviceChain.add(new MessageDetector());
    class MyAdvice implements MethodInterceptor {

        @Override
        public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("in myAdvice before, hasmessage:" + hasMessage.get());
            Object proceed = invocation.proceed();
            System.out.println("in myAdvice after, hasmessage:" + hasMessage.get());
            latch.countDown();
            return proceed;
        }

    }
    adviceChain.add(new MyAdvice());
    adapter.setAdviceChain(adviceChain);
    adapter.setTrigger(new Trigger() {

        @Override
        public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
            return null; // never poll
        }
    });
    adapter.start();
    adapter.stop();
    adapter.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(1000));
    adapter.start();
    assertTrue(latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gary, I'm fairly new to SI and was trying to adapt the offer post to my situation. Anyway, adding a MethodInterceptor into the poller advice chain works. Also added it programmatically, as only needed within test, but in what seems a dirty way, would be interested to know how you get a reference to the pollerMetadata, I'm using getPropertyValues from the adapter.  But main issue is that the adapter is clearing the latch even when no mail is received. So we have a race condition meaning the test sometimes passes sometimes fails.

Comment: I'm liking this technique, is a lot neater. But the advice is not being called. I'll update the question with what I have.

Comment: Neither setting the advice chain within the test or setting it within the postProcessAfterInitialization method have an effect. The adapter poller is created before these occur, so setting the advice chain has no effect on the poller. Can modify the SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean within the postProcessBeforeInitialization, but a bit messy to not completely override the PollerMetadata.

Comment: Sorry; I forgot one more important step - we need to reset the `initialized` flag. We can either do that with reflection or, if you set an `initialDelay` on the poller, `start(); stop(); start()` will work. I'll edit my answer with a complete test case.

Comment: That's the one! great thanks. Handily the poller returns true is a message was received, so I just check the proceed value before counting down the latch.