# Add adviceChain to StandardIntegrationFlow to set a CountDownLatch on a message handler

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I´m trying to add a `CountDownLatch` to an `org.springframework.integration.dsl.StandardIntegrationFlow` in Spring Integration via an `adviceChain` and the `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`. The reason for this is to monitor, if the message handler within this integration flow was called and has finished his work or not.

There is a solution without using the Java DSL of Spring Integration here: [spring-integration unit test outbound-channel adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16277487/spring-integration-unit-test-outbound-channel-adapter). But sadly it´s not working for me because of the Java DSL and the `StandardIntegrationFlow`. Gary Russels solution looks like this: https://gist.github.com/garyrussell/5481779. My exception trying this is:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: 
Invalid property 'adviceChain' of bean class [org.springframework.integration.dsl.StandardIntegrationFlow]: 
Bean property 'adviceChain' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

The integration flow looks like this:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow myFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(myChannel())
            .handle(message -> manager.handleMessage(message))
            .get();
}
```

I need to add a `CountDownLatch` to the `.handle()` part, thus enabling me to ask the latch if the handler has finished its work.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IntegrationFlow` essentially does nothing with integration at all. It is a logical container for real Spring Integration endpoints and message channels between them. So, if you are talking about the advice exactly for the `.handle()`, what is really correct, you should consider to do this:

```
.handle(message -> manager.handleMessage(message), e -> e.advice(...))
```

Where that `advice()` is about:

```
/**
 * Configure a list of {@link Advice} objects to be applied, in nested order, to the
 * endpoint's handler. The advice objects are applied only to the handler.
 * @param advice the advice chain.
 * @return the endpoint spec.
 */
public S advice(Advice... advice) {
```

Comment: That's certainly the easiest way; you could use `e.advice(advice())` where the `advice()` bean is an empty array for production but the latch advise for tests. It's a bit more tricky to avoid the `.advice(...)` and add an advice just for a test case; easy enough with a `BeanPostProcessor` for a simple `MessageHandler` such as the one in the question; for an `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler`, since the advice has to be applied internally, the BPP would have to inject the advice into the bean before initialization.

Comment: For the testing purpose consider to use newly added Testing features: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.M6/reference/html/testing.html#test-context, where you don't need to think about advices if your can just replace it with the `mockMessageHandler()` in the target test-case.

Comment: Thanks both of you! I´ll try the new M6 testing features. But in case it won´t work for us @GaryRussell: How would you use the BPP to add the advice? I don´t like the idea of introducing test-only code into my production code...

Comment: @ArtemBilan When using `mockIntegrationContext.substituteMessageHandlerFor()`, I need to supply the bean name of the consumer (to be replaced with the mock), but since I´m using the Java DSL, I´m not sure which name to put here. I tested a few, but every try leads to `Bean named 'xyz' is expected to be of type 'org.springframework.integration.endpoint.IntegrationConsumer'`. How can I substitute the message handler as shown in my example in the question above?

Comment: The `e` in my sample has an `id()` option. That defines the bean name for the consumer endpoint based on your `MessageHandler`

Comment: @ArtemBilan Works like a charm! Thank you :).

Comment: Cool! I would like to hear more feedback about our new Spring Integration Testing Framework and extend and improve it as much as possible. Feel free to come back to us on JIRA with any ideas on the matter!